# How do i remove the href on popup's close button in Leaflet?

Tags: vue.js, leaflet, vuejs3

In a Vue app, the close button on the markers popup change the URL by adding #close, making the page change.

Can I remove it?

[Marker popup example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eLN6q.png)

Comment: You might not show the close button setting [`closeButton`](https://leafletjs.com/reference.html#popup-closebutton) to `false`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I disable or change the href on a React-Leaflet v4 Popup close button?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72020795/how-can-i-disable-or-change-the-href-on-a-react-leaflet-v4-popup-close-button)

Answer (score 0):

I recommended you to read [leaflet doc for marker](https://leafletjs.com/reference.html#popup)
you will see that you can hide button close by set option `closeButton: false`