# How to stop leaflet popup closing (x) button redirecting to (href= /#close),is there any way

Tags: javascript, reactjs, leaflet, react-leaflet

my react app has leaflet map and it has popup as well at the top of the popup  has `x` button clicking on it app redirect to the `/#close` i don't want this to happen, how to stop this, my leaflet v - 1.7.1

i  assume code snippet is required

i tried downgrade leaflet 1.7.0 but still issues persist and tried couple of example still issue did not get resolved

Thanks in advnc

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Look here - [leaflet/issues](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/issues/8159)

Comment: Upgrade to Leaflet `v1.9.3`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I disable or change the href on a React-Leaflet v4 Popup close button?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72020795/how-can-i-disable-or-change-the-href-on-a-react-leaflet-v4-popup-close-button)